# Semantic UI: How to prevent form from being submitted when validation fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have a basic login form and I've specified the form validations and API call in my javascript file. The problem that I have is, when I click the login button and the form has errors, the invalid fields will be highlighted but the API call is still made, even though the form is invalid.

Here's a simplified example:

```
<form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="ui submit button">Login</button>
  <div class="ui error message"></div>
</form>
```

---

```
$(function() {

    $('form').form({
        username: {
            identifier: 'username',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your username'
            }]
        },
        password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your password'
            }]
        }
    }, {
        onFailure: function() {
            // prevent form submission (doesn't work)
            return false;
        }
    });

    // *** this API call should not be made when the form is invalid ***
    $('form .submit.button').api({
        action: 'login',
        method: 'post',
        serializeForm: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        onSuccess: function() {
            // todo
        },
        onError: function() {
            // todo
        }
    });

});
```

I also have a punkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttLq1owlQLsLSpG6SUPy) which demonstrates the issue I'm having.

Did I miss something? Are the `.api()` and `.form()` calls correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. All I need to do is change

```
$('form .submit.button').api(...
```

to

```
$('form').api(...
```

I didn't realise that I could call `.api()` directly on the `<form>` element. Now the api call isn't made when the form is invalid because the form isn't submitted (previously I had the api call on the submit button which isn't cancelled when the form is invalid).

Comment: `$('form').api(...` is wrong. the form will not start validation when you click the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Use onSuccess event instead of api method.

```
$('form').form({
        username: {
            identifier: 'username',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your username'
            }]
        },
        password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please enter your password'
            }]
        }
    }, {
        onFailure: function() {
            // prevent form submission (doesn't work)
            return false;
        },
         onSuccess:function(event,fields){
            // prevent form submission
            // api / ajax call
          return false;
        }
    });
```